# Single gradient to multiple images

Tags: css, effects

I would get this result:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsbo5.jpg)

the images will be cropped in PNG without background and and black color,
like the gradient in separate images its possible with CSS ?

Comment: yes, you can specify multiple elements, where css-properties should be applied. eg. `#img1, #img2 { opacity: 0.5; }`

Comment: but thus specifying the images were staying with the same gradient.
the first image starts yellow and the last is green

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to place the images inside of a `div` and then style the `div`'s background with the desired gradient. For example:

HTML

```
<div id="gradient">
    <img src="..." /><img src="..." /><img src="..." />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#gradient {
    width: 300px; //Whatever the total width of the images is
    height: 61px; //Whatever the height of the images is
    ...  //Gradient CSS goes here
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2aHHu/